# How to add a physical disk to TrueNAS that hosted as a VM

Tags: network-attached-storage, truenas

I got this error while trying to create a `pool` in TrueNAS Core.

`[EFAULT] Failed to wipe disk ada1: [EFAULT] Command gpart create -s gpt /dev/ada1 failed (code 1): gpart: Input/output error`

Here's my setup:

- Windows 10 Pro as the host
- TrueNAS Core 12.0 hosted in VirtualBox 6.1
- A 2TB VHD attached to TrueNAS via VirtualBox as Primary Slave

The 2TB disk is recognized in TrueNAS under Storage > Disks.

But got error below when trying to create Storage > Pools >  Create

```
[EFAULT] Failed to wipe disk ada1: [EFAULT] Command gpart create -s gpt /dev/ada1 failed (code 1): gpart: Input/output error
Error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/middlewared/job.py", line 361, in run
    await self.future
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/middlewared/job.py", line 397, in __run_body
    rv = await self.method(*([self] + args))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/middlewared/schema.py", line 973, in nf
    return await f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/middlewared/plugins/pool.py", line 655, in do_create
    formatted_disks = await self.middleware.call('pool.format_disks', job, disks)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/middlewared/main.py", line 1238, in call
    return await self._call(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/middlewared/main.py", line 1195, in _call
    return await methodobj(*prepared_call.args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/middlewared/plugins/pool_/format_disks.py", line 56, in format_disks
    await asyncio_map(format_disk, disks.items(), limit=16)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/middlewared/utils/asyncio_.py", line 16, in asyncio_map
    return await asyncio.gather(*futures)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/middlewared/utils/asyncio_.py", line 13, in func
    return await real_func(arg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/middlewared/plugins/pool_/format_disks.py", line 29, in format_disk
    await self.middleware.call(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/middlewared/main.py", line 1238, in call
    return await self._call(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/middlewared/main.py", line 1206, in _call
    return await self.run_in_executor(prepared_call.executor, methodobj, *prepared_call.args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/middlewared/main.py", line 1110, in run_in_executor
    return await loop.run_in_executor(pool, functools.partial(method, *args, **kwargs))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/middlewared/utils/io_thread_pool_executor.py", line 25, in run
    result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/middlewared/plugins/disk_/format.py", line 25, in format
    raise CallError(f'Failed to wipe disk {disk}: {job.error}')
middlewared.service_exception.CallError: [EFAULT] Failed to wipe disk ada1: [EFAULT] Command gpart create -s gpt /dev/ada1 failed (code 1):
gpart: Input/output error
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a virtual hard disk in VDI format and it works this time. VHD format didn't work for unknown reasons.